# Dialog windows not closing

Tags: ui

Most of the the popup dialogs are not properly closing anymore on our site. Instead when I click the action button it keeps spinning and the dialog remains open. It happens on most of the dialogs, e.g. new activity inside contact summary, new ACL role, delete confirmations etc.
There is no error in the browser console and the server request returns with success.
It seems to be an issue in my environment as it hasn't always been like that.

I am on CiviCRM 5.62.1, Drupal 9 and the Finsbury Park theme but it occurs with Greenwich as well.

Comment: As a workaround you can turn off popups, at administer - customize - display prefs. Near the bottom.

Comment: Thank you! That works around some use cases, others like new activity/new organisation inside contact are still using popups though.